# How to stop block level elements from expanding through a floated element

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-2

I'm using Twitter Bootstrap 2.3.2 to create a stacked nav next to a floated div. You can see it here:
https://www.tntech.edu/studentaffairs/orientation-and-student-success/

For some reason the list elements are expanding through the info box div which is floated right. I can't understand why. The P elements above it work like normal. What gives?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: wrap the content, which is supposed to be on the left side in another div and float it to the left. don't forget to add an empty div with a clear:both style afterwards for a correct calculation.

Comment: Just as a note the `p` elements behave the same as the `li` elements. You will see that when you add a background color to those `p` elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just slap `overflow: auto` on your `ul` like so:

```
 .nav.nav-pills.nav-stacked {
    overflow: auto;
 }
```

And that will solve it.

The reason this works is that setting a specified overflow (other than `visible`, the default) will create a new block formatting context, forcing the element to respect the bounds of the floated element's block formatting context.

Take a look at the **[Block Formatting Context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Block_formatting_context)** spec, too.  It's fascinating.

Answer (score 1):

Nobody is explaining the basic rule of floated elements adjacent to no floated block elements.  In your example, you have something which is floated first, followed by other non-floated blocks:

```
<ul>floated</ul>
<h1>not floated</h1>
<p>not floated</p>
<ul>not floated</ul>
<h3>not floated</h3>
```

**If you applied a background to all of those non-floated elements, you would see that they all spill behind the floated one.**  The browser is smart enough to wrap the text accordingly, but the containing block still fills the entire width of the container.

[image: screenshot of floats and blocks]

This is just a thing you have to deal with.  Once you understand it, you can use it to your power.  If you don't want those items to spill behind the floated one, I suggest using margins:

```
.floated {
    float: right;
    width: 250px;
}
/* for anything that comes after a .floated element */
.floated + * {
    margin-right: 280px;
}
```

Comment: I never realized that it was only the text that was wrapping around floated elements and not the whole element. It makes perfect sense now though. I accepted a different answer because the solution presented there worked best for me but this is good information too. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

it's because the `<ul>` element is styled as `float:none`; which according to the standard:

> The element is not floated, and will be displayed just where it occurs
>   in the text. This is default

Set it to float:left or create a rule with a width for the ul and that should fix it.